# css добавить цвет черной svg фигуре (без html фильтров), или mask для IE

Tags: css3, svg, internet-explorer, mask

У меня есть черная svg фигура галочки. Ее ставлю фоном элемента в его :before. Нужно задать цвет этой галочки.

в нормальных браузерах - Firefox, Chromium

```
        background: #26e33c;
        mask: data-uri('image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8', '../images/check0.svg') 0 0 / cover;
        mask-size: cover;
```

для IE и мобильных не работает оно.

Нашел такой ответ:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...><g stroke="red" ... /></g></svg>');
```

можно ли сюда вместо ... вставить ../images/chack.svg ?

Или как можно сделать рабочим mask для IE и мобильеых?

вроде, должно работать в эдже, но нет:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MaskFilter(color=#26448c)";
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MaskFilter(color=#26448c);
```

Comment: а use нельзя применять ?

Answer (score 2):

Всякую векторную одноцветную мелочь рекомендую подключать при помощи иконочных шрифтов. Это позволяет средствами обычного `css` изменять размер и цвет иконок, а также является кроссбраузерным решением.
 Можно использовать как готовые шрифты(в примере **FontAwesome 4.7**), так и создавать свои собственные из отдельных svg-иконок(рекомендую https://icomoon.io/app/).

```css
i:hover{
  color:red;
}
.pseudo:before{
  content:'\f00c';
  font-family:fontAwesome;
}
.pseudo:hover:before{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p>Стандартное включение иконок в разметку: <i class="fa fa-check"></i></p>
<p class="pseudo">С помощью псевдоэлементов</p>
```

Comment: для галочки даже font-awesome не нужен ...`&#10004;`

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , таки да. Правда юникодовская галочка в разных браузерах по разному выглядит

Comment: у меня psd макет. там конкретная галочка, так что это не подходит

Comment: отличие не сильное вроде бы

Comment: @CodeGust  эта иконка просто чёрная и всё ? в svg отрисовал её ?

Comment: да, черный svg. это макет, я его не делал, должен сверстать как есть, с использованием тех ресурсов

Comment: @CodeGust  вы бы саму SVGшку показали бы ...

Comment: @CodeGust, можно и из своих иконок сделать шрифт https://icomoon.io/app/

Comment: svg очень похожа. но если бы и точно такая, должен ресурс использовать.

Comment: @CodeGust , если уж так не хочется заморачиваться с иконочными шрифтами, можно создать две галочки разных цветов (например `chack.svg` и `chack-red.svg`) и при наведении менять `background-image`.